# Bash: Filter lines by matching to number range

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file **test** with fields: *cato*, and *pos*.

```
1   7100
1   35000
1   49321
1   49759
2   44842
2   52794
2   53558
3   53859
3   54013
3   55172
```

I have a file **db** with fields: *cato*, *start* and *stop*.

```
1   6408    8000
1   11822   16373
1   18716   23389
1   27690   34330
1   36552   39191
1   39313   44565
2   44839   50247
2   60987   65017
2   65705   71523
```

My aim is to pick rows in file **db** where field `pos` from file **test** falls within the range *start* and *stop* of file **db**. There is the restriction that the match has to happen within a *cato* group. Both files are sorted by fields 1 and 2. As a side note, both my real files have many other fields as well.

With this example dataset, my expected result would be:

```
1   6408    8000
2   44839   50247
```

I have a script that I have mashed up.

```
k=1;
data_test=$(cat "test")
data_db=$(cat "db")
while read -r line
do
  # helps to keep count of test rows
  printf "$k \n"

  # get cato
  cato=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
  # get pos
  pos=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
  # get number of chars in pos (to reduce number of lines awk needs to look through later)
  pos_chr=$(echo -n $pos | wc -c)
  # get lines in db that start with cato and pos chars match start or stop
  matched=$(echo "$data_db" | grep -Ew "^$cato" | grep -Ew "[0-9]{$pos_chr}")
  #echo "$db_cat"

  # if matched is not empty
  if [ ! -z "$matched" ]; then
    # use awk to print lines in db where pos > start and pos < stop
    echo "$matched" | awk -v apos='$pos' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{if(apos >= $2 && apos <= $3) print $0}'
    #check
    #echo "$matched" | awk -v apos=$pos 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print apos,$0}'
  fi

  ((k=k+1))
done <<< "$data_test"
```

It seems like `awk` doesn't do the comparison in the last step. Things seem to work till the last step and then I am not sure what is wrong. Perhaps someone sees the error. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `awk --version GNU Awk 3.1.7`

Comment: I found that changing `apos='$pos'` to `apos=$pos` makes it work. But, this code is way too slow for large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With single GNU **`awk`** program (since `Gawk` v4.0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1][$2]; next }
     $1 in a{ 
         for (i in a[$1]) 
             if (i >= $2 && i <= $3) { print $0; break }
     }' test db
```

The output:

```
1   6408    8000
2   44839   50247
```

Comment: I seem to get syntax error pointing at the square bracket `[`.

Comment: @rmf, unfortunately, `gawk v.3` is pretty outdated. Array of arrays feature was implemented in `gawk` v.4

Comment: Aha! Turns out I do have `gawk 4.1.4` as well and it works on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` with a simple `test`:

```
$ cat is-between.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read cato start stop pos; do
    [ $start -le $pos -a $pos -le $stop ] && echo "$cato $start $stop"
done < <(join db test)

$ ./is-between.sh
1 6408 8000
2 44839 50247
```

You have relational data: key values in one file match key values in another, row-by-row. `join` is the tool to bring these together. Run `join db test` and you'll notice it's the same result as a `SELECT * FROM db JOIN test on test.cato=db.cato` if the data were in a database.

With this in hand, you now have rows that place start, stop, and pos on a line. Looping over these, using a `test` to check the range, is then easy.